# How to use a different json parser for jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have json data with "tagged" values (from a `jsonp` source):

```
{"foo": "@duration:8542"}
```

which I can parse on-the-fly by passing a function as the second argument to JSON.parse:

```
dk.json = {
    parse: function (s) {
        return JSON.parse(s, function (key, val) {
            if (typeof val === 'string' && val[0] === '@') {
                var colonpos = val.indexOf(':');
                if (colonpos > 1) {
                    var tag = val.slice(0, colonpos + 1);
                    switch (tag) {
                        case dk.Date.tag:       return dk.Date.create(val);
                        case dk.Duration.tag:   return dk.Duration.create(val);
                    }
                }
            }
            return val;
        });
    },
    //...
};
```

but how can I plug this parsing function into `jQuery.ajax()`?  Something more sensible than:

```
success: function (data) {
    data = dk.json.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    ...
```

`dataFilter`, and especially `converters` looked promising:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    converters: {
        'text json': dk.json.parse
    },
    // ...
});
```

but that doesn't get called at all (dataFilter gets called, but with the data parameter set to undefined).

Where am I going wrong?

[Edit:]

I know I can write a traversal function that walks the JSON object returned by jQuery, eg:

```
function untag(val) {
    if (typeof val === 'string' && val[0] === '@') {
        var colonpos = val.indexOf(':');
        if (colonpos > 1) {
            var tag = val.slice(0, colonpos + 1);
            switch (tag) {
                case dk.Date.tag:     return dk.Date.create(val);
                case dk.Duration.tag: return dk.Duration.create(val);
            }
        }
    }
    return val;
}

var untag_json = function (jsonobj) {
    var _traverse = function _traverse(obj, result) {
        var value;
        for (var attr in obj) {
            value = obj[attr];
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                result[attr] = _traverse(value, {});
            } else {
                result[attr] = untag(value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    };

    return _traverse(jsonobj, {});
};
```

and then call it in the `success` handler:

```
success: function (data) {
    data = untag_json(data);
    ...
```

but that seems like a lot of unnecessary work.. Is there no way to use the `converters` parameter to `$.ajax` to get access to the unparsed (i.e. text) json source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually isn't any JSON parsing in a JSONP request ([src](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/jsonp.js)), which can seem counter intuitive.  What is happening is the string that is returning from the JSONP endpoint is evaluated as JavaScript (with a reference to a function that is defined (or added in dynamically) in the DOM making the JSONP request like this:

```
_callback({'foo':'@duration:8524'});
```

If you wanted to use your function you would need to make the endpoint return a String like this:

```
_callback("{'foo':'@duration:8524'}");
```

then in the JSONP callback you could call `JSON.parse()`.  JSON parse is a rather safe way to process JSON so if this was easier to reason about then it would be a fine approach.

Comment: You're a genius :-)   Single quotes aren't valid json, so I ended up returning (python): `callback + "(dk.json.parse(%s))" % json.dumps(json.dumps(value))`.  The first `callback` is the `success` function received from jQuery, the nested `json.dumps()` calls first convert `value` to json, and then json to string (not really, but I think you know what I mean)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to set this header application/json in the response from server side then you can simply set dataType:json or dataType:jsonp then you will not need to stringify or parse the json. You then just get objects, properties or arrays from json.

For example : in php we use

```
$json_string = "{"foo": "@duration:8542"}";
$json = json_decode($json_string); 
$foo = $json->foo;
echo $foo;//prints @duration:8542
```

In jquery you can do this:

```
sucess:function(response) {
  var foo = response.foo;
  console.log(foo);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you've misunderstood... I want the parsed json to be an object similar to

    `{foo: dk.Duration.create('@duration:8524')}`

i.e. the '@duration:8524' string should be converted to a dk.Duration object during json parsing.

Comment: Your jQuery function only prints out the string "@duration:8542", which is not `isinstance` of `dk.Duration`...

Comment: what happen if you pass this value to `dk.Duration.create()` my guess is it may create that instance from the value.

Comment: Yes, of course, but the whole point is to have that happen automatically during parsing of the json string.  That is what the second argument to JSON.parse (the `reviver` parameter) is for.  See e.g.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse  Since I can do it with the native JSON.parse call... who can I do it when using `jQuery.ajax(..)`?

Comment: What will be your JSON format? If you have array of objects like below: `{"data":[{'foo':'@duration:8524'},{'tag':'somvaluelikeother'}]}` then you can parse this using jQuery `success:function(response){$.each(response.data,function(key,value){ switch(value){case dk.Date.tag:       return dk.Date.create(value);break;
                        case dk.Duration.tag:   return dk.Duration.create(value);break; }})}`

Comment: That isn't really parsing, and my data format will be much more complex than that, and potentially recursive.  I could write a recursive traversal algorithm that would switch out the tagged strings with objects, but that seems like a lot of work for (a) something that is already built into the browsers' `JSON.parse` implementation, and (b) unlikely to be much faster than `data = dk.json.parse(JSON.stringify(data));` as mentioned in the question.  Isn't this exactly the use-case for the `converters` parameter to `$.ajax()`?